# How To Set NetFlow Cisco SF200-24 using WEB UI

Tags: router, switch, setup

is Cisco SF200-24 switch support netflow? if it's support netflow. how can i set it up through WEB UI, i have found on internet but it using command line. i'm new in setting up switch.

[here is the sample WebUI of Cisco SF200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8GeZ.png)
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOHO switches like the Cisco SF200-24 do not support NetFlow or any other similar flow format.**

SLFOW v.5 was introduced with software version 2.1.0 for [other Cisco models](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/csbss/sf_sg250/release_notes/R_2_1_0_RN.pdf).

> SLFOW v5—An embedded sampling technology (based on RFC 3176) that 
>   provides the ability to continuously 
>   monitor traffic flows and counters on 
>   some or all interfaces simultaneously. The sFlow monitoring system 
>   consists of the sFlow Agent (embedded in the device) and a central data 
>   collector, or sFlow Analyzer.